# Krustlet bootstrap bash script on minikube

Tags: shell, kubectl, minikube

I was attempting to run a hello-world demo of [Krustlet](https://github.com/krustlet/krustlet) on [minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/).
According to Krustlet's [official tutorial](https://docs.krustlet.dev/howto/krustlet-on-minikube/), there is [step](https://docs.krustlet.dev/howto/bootstrapping/) to generate a bootstrap config with a utility [script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/second-state/wasmedge-containers-examples/main/crio/install.sh).

Since I was running minikube without `kubectl` manually installed, I had to use `minikube kubectl` rather than `kubectl`. So I also did this replacement in the script and tried to run it with `bash bootstrap.sh`. However, the result was a complaint:

```
Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'f' in -f
See 'minikube kubectl --help' for usage.
```

Please, any help?

Answer (score 0):

First look at the `bash minikube kubectl --help` [page](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/kubectl/):

```
      --add_dir_header                   If true, adds the file directory to the header of the log messages
      --alsologtostderr                  log to standard error as well as files
  -b, --bootstrapper string              The name of the cluster bootstrapper that will set up the Kubernetes cluster. (default "kubeadm")
  -h, --help                             
      --log_backtrace_at traceLocation   when logging hits line file:N, emit a stack trace (default :0)
      --log_dir string                   If non-empty, write log files in this directory
      --log_file string                  If non-empty, use this log file
      --log_file_max_size uint           Defines the maximum size a log file can grow to. Unit is megabytes. If the value is 0, the maximum file size is unlimited. (default 1800)
      --logtostderr                      log to standard error instead of files
      --one_output                       If true, only write logs to their native severity level (vs also writing to each lower severity level)
  -p, --profile string                   The name of the minikube VM being used. This can be set to allow having multiple instances of minikube independently. (default "minikube")
      --skip_headers                     If true, avoid header prefixes in the log messages
      --skip_log_headers                 If true, avoid headers when opening log files
      --stderrthreshold severity         logs at or above this threshold go to stderr (default 2)
      --user string                      Specifies the user executing the operation. Useful for auditing operations executed by 3rd party tools. Defaults to the operating system username.
  -v, --v Level                          number for the log level verbosity
      --vmodule moduleSpec               comma-separated list of pattern=N settings for file-filtered logging
```

This is a very simple command and does not support the `-f` flag.  To solve this problem you can [install full kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/) command. You can find the guide also [here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/). Of course you can also setup your cluster not in Minikube. Basically, you need to have `kubectl` command to run your script.

Comment: Thx for reply, but I think this complaint rise at line 14 `cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -`. Run `minikube kubectl apply --help` and it says `-f, --filename=[]: that contains the configuration to apply`.